# Pass PHP var to Python script

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to pass a var from php to my python script, however it doesn't seem to work, I've looked at different forum posts and can't seem to get it working, where am I going wrong?
The var in the python script is for the first sleep

Here is my php script:

```
$var1 = $_GET['speed'];
$command = escapeshellcmd('python /var/www/html/blink.py $var1');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Here is my python script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import shlex
from subprocess import call
import sys

while (True):

    # Turn all relays ON
    call(shlex.split('gpio mode 1 out'))
    call(shlex.split('gpio write 1 0'))

    # Sleep for 5 seconds
    sleep(sys.argv[1]) 
    # Turn all relays OFF
    call(shlex.split('gpio write 1 1'))

    # Sleep for 5 seconds
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is a string, you'll need to convert that to a number. Call: `sleep(int(sys.argv[1]))`, with error checking.

Comment: can you add a simple `print(sys.argv)` to the python script and show us what does it outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, single quotes don't expand variables. Unless you're trying to send the literal string `$var1` to your python script, you will need to change `$command = escapeshellcmd('python /var/www/html/blink.py $var1');` to expand the variable.

One way is `$command = escapeshellcmd('python /var/www/html/blink.py ' . $var1);`

Comment: Edit your answer to explicitly show what the fix is please.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work I'm afraid, it still posts to the python script, but doesn't pass the variable through

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an intermediate variable to concatenate the command line and the argument:

```
$var1 = $_GET['speed'];
$tmp = 'python /var/www/html/blink.py ' . $var1;
$command = escapeshellcmd($tmp);
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

I tried and it works just fine.